# How can I disable NTLMv1, LM, and LMv2 on up-to-date Windows 10 machines?

Tags: windows

How can I disable NTLMv1, LM, and LMv2 on up-to-date Windows 10 machines?  I obviously don't have group policy, so I need to know the relevant registry keys and what to set them to.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off topic here. You'll have to look that up in the documentation.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Did you try to run `gpedit.msc`? The obvious answer to your question is to use a group policy.

Comment: @Seth This is a home version of Windows.  I don't have group policy.

Comment: [GPSearch on Azurewebsites](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net) might be useful for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable all versions of NTLM on home versions of Windows 7, 8.1, and 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1290414/how-can-i-disable-all-versions-of-ntlm-on-home-versions-of-windows-7-8-1-and-1)

Answer (score 0):

Set the NTLM compatibility level to 5.

Comment: Please describe how to do this.  Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.